# How to specify many ids and their variable name in a REST API request?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

What is the most common and wise way to specify many entities' ids in an API request?

For a singular entity request I have:

```
GET /v1/entities/{entity_id}
```

My suggestions for requesting many entities:

```
GET /v1/entities?entity_ids={entity_id1},{entity_id2}
```

With the same variable name entity_id:

```
GET /v1/entities?entity_id={entity_id1},{entity_id2}
```

More looks like for singular endpoint:

```
GET /v1/entities/{entity_id1},{entity_id2}
```

Or is there any other way to design for such endpoints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm afraid the standard thing to do is not to search multiple ids like this using REST.  If you're loading several *specific* entities by id, then you should ask yourself why you're doing so.  Perhaps these entities are customer orders belonging to a specific customer and you're loading the details of each order.  In that case, you should have a URL more like `/customer/{id}/orders` which returns all orders belonging to a customer with id `{id}` rather than knowing the ids beforehand and loading them each individually.

Otherwise if the user is attempting to load several entities from a list to view its details, simplify the display to show one entity detail at a time, and you load each one as the user moves forwards or backwards.  In other words, you shouldn't be in a situation where you'd specifically need multiple entities loaded by their ids with no obvious link between them that you'd need a way to call the REST service with each individual id listed.

Answer (score 0):

All these approaches share the same issue: they bloat the request string when many IDs are queried. When there are cases when many IDs are requested you can likely get into the situation where a gateway server rejects the request because the query string exceeds some limit (usually around ~2000 chars).

With that in minde none of these options is any wiser than the other.

I have seen the last approach in several APIs while i have not seen any of the others. I recommend you go with

```
/entities/id1,id2
```

---

A side note: dont do API versioning via the URL if you want to be RESTful. Entity#5 ist still Entity#5, no matter what the API version is that you access it through. The consensus is to use header for the versioning:

```
X-API-Version: 1
```

Comment: That is *not* "the consensus".